# SolidWorks API How to use SelectByID2 method

Tags: vba, api, solidworks

How to create a reference plane by using InsertRefPlane method which requires SelectByID2 method in SolidWorks API in an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The goal is to create a reference plane by only selecting three vertices.

First we need to declare and initialize needed variables/objects. Then we obtain points from the SelectionManager from which we need to extract coordinates. These coordinates will help us since we can specify vertex coordinates to successfuly select and mark them using SelectByID2 method.

```
' Create reference plane with three vertices

' Prerequisites: Opened part with three selected vertices
' Result: Reference plane which lies in the plane formed by three vertices

Dim swApp As SldWorks.SldWorks

Sub main()
Dim swModel As SldWorks.ModelDoc2
Dim swPart As SldWorks.PartDoc
Dim swSelMgr As SldWorks.SelectionMgr
Dim swModelDocExt As SldWorks.ModelDocExtension
Dim faceObj As SldWorks.Face2
Dim vertexObj As SldWorks.Vertex

Set swApp = Application.SldWorks
Set swModel = swApp.ActiveDoc
Set swModelExt = swModel.Extension
Set swSelMgr = swModel.SelectionManager

' Declare and initialise needed variables
Dim bool As Boolean
Dim numSelectedObjs As Integer
Dim selMark As Long
Dim selObjectType() As Long
Dim selObject() As Object
Dim ptCtr As Integer: ptCtr = 1
Dim ptObjArr As Variant
Dim ptVar() As Variant
Dim i, j As Integer
selMark = -1

' Check selection and reallocate needed objects
numSelectedObjs = swSelMgr.GetSelectedObjectCount2(selMark)
If (numSelectedObjs <> 3) Then
    MsgBox "You must select three vertices to create a plane"
    End
ElseIf (numSelectedObjs = 0) Then
    MsgBox "No vertices selected"
    End
End If
ReDim Preserve selObjectType(numSelectedObjs - 1)
ReDim Preserve selObject(numSelectedObjs - 1)

' Traverse selection and obtain vertex coordinates
For i = 1 To numSelectedObjs
    selObjectType(i - 1) = swSelMgr.GetSelectedObjectType3(i, selMark)
    If (selObjectType(i - 1) = SwConst.swSelVERTICES) Then 'Identify selection
        Set vertexObj = swSelMgr.GetSelectedObject6(i, selMark)
        Set selObject(i - 1) = vertexObj
        ptObjArr = swSelMgr.GetSelectionPoint2(i, selMark)
        ReDim Preserve ptVar(ptCtr - 1)
        ptVar(ptCtr - 1) = ptObjArr
        ptCtr = ptCtr + 1
    'ElseIf (selObjectType(i - 1) = SwConst.swSelFACES) Then
    'ElseIf (selObjectType(i - 1) = SwConst.swSelEDGES) Then
    End If
Next
'
' Clear selection and proceed with marking the points for InsertReferencePlane using SelectByID2 method
swModel.ClearSelection2 (True)

Dim selAppend As Boolean: selAppend = False
Dim objMark As Long: objMark = 0
Dim objCallout As Callout
Dim selOption As swSelectOption_e: selOption = 0
For i = 1 To numSelectedObjs
    If (i = 1) Then
        selAppend = False
    Else
        selAppend = True
    End If
    objMark = i - 1
    selBool = swModel.Extension.SelectByID2("", "", ptVar(i - 1)(0), ptVar(i - 1)(1), ptVar(i - 1)(2), selAppend, objMark, objCallout, selOption)
    Debug.Print selBool
Next

' Reference plane
' Creating the reference plane
Dim refPlaneObj As SldWorks.RefPlane
Dim firstCon As Long: firstCon = SwConst.swRefPlaneReferenceConstraint_Coincident
Dim firstConVal As Long: firstConVal = 0
Dim secondCon As Long: secondCon = SwConst.swRefPlaneReferenceConstraint_Coincident
Dim secondConVal As Long: secondConVal = 0
Dim thirdCon As Long: thirdCon = SwConst.swRefPlaneReferenceConstraint_Coincident
Dim thirdConVal As Long: thirdConVal = 0
Set refPlaneObj = swModel.FeatureManager.InsertRefPlane(firstCon, firstConVal, _
                                                        secondCon, secondConVal, _
                                                        thirdCon, thirdConVal)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

> Actually it looks like there might be issues because the CAD model is
> imported and faces are faces are non-planar.

Hi Mario,

You can check if the selected face is planar by using:

```
Face.IGetSurface().IsPlane()
```

Eddy

Answer (score 1):

There could be many reasons why I doesn't work for you.
Without your complete code, it would be difficult to help you.

If your selection get deselected, it might be because you set "Attempt" to False.
Also "Mark" needs to be "0" for the first selection, and "1" for the second.
Look at the remarks and examples in [InsertRefPlane](http://help.solidworks.com/2019/english/api/sldworksapi/solidworks.interop.sldworks%7Esolidworks.interop.sldworks.ifeaturemanager%7Einsertrefplane.html)

The best way to get a base for your code is to start recording a macro, manually insert a plane then stop and edit the code.

Also SelectByID2 is not the only method to select a face, there is also [SelectByRay](https://help.solidworks.com/2017/English/api/sldworksapi/SolidWorks.interop.sldworks%7ESolidWorks.interop.sldworks.IModelDocExtension%7ESelectByRay.html), or cycle through all the entities with [GetFirstFace](https://help.solidworks.com/2020/English/api/sldworksapi/SOLIDWORKS.Interop.sldworks%7ESOLIDWORKS.Interop.sldworks.IBody2%7EGetFirstFace.html) / [GetNextFace](https://help.solidworks.com/2016/English/api/sldworksapi/SOLIDWORKS.Interop.sldworks%7ESOLIDWORKS.Interop.sldworks.IFace2%7EGetNextFace.html) or [GetFaces](https://help.solidworks.com/2016/English/api/sldworksapi/SOLIDWORKS.Interop.sldworks%7ESOLIDWORKS.Interop.sldworks.IBody2%7EGetFaces.html) to find the one you want.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. 

I have included my code and included a little bit more information to clarify my issue.

Comment: Actually it looks like there might be issues because the CAD model is imported and faces are faces are non-planar.